# ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$ into $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$.

Tags: ring-theory, abstract-algebra

A question from Gallian which I had in my exam says:

Suppose $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$ into $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$.What are the possibilities for $\phi((1,0))?$

Any idea,How to go with this?Please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $(1,0)\cdot(1,0)=(1,0)$, so it is an idempotent element (solution of $x^2=x$). Therefore it has to go to some element with the same property. As the product structure on the direct sum is given component-wise, every component of an idempotent element is idempotent in its corresponding factor… i.e. $(a,b)$ is idempotent iff $a^2=a$ and $b^2=b$, so from this you restrict your possibilities to $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,0)$.
Obviously, the first and the last are possible (the identity homomorphism and the null homomorphism). Also the second is just $(a,b)\mapsto (b,a)$. Now you just have to decide if $(1,1)$ is possible…

Comment: Thanks for answer but I still can't connect between idempotent element and homomorphism here....I mean what benefit did we get by finding $(1,0)$ is idempotent .Please if you can  help  clarify this...

Comment: If $x$ is an idempotent element of $R$ and $\phi:R\to R'$ is a ring homomorphism, then $\phi(x)$ is idempotent in $R'$ … This means, as I have written above, that, through a homomorphism $(1,0)$ has to go to some other idempotent element … and there are only four…

Comment: As for $(1,1)$, just try to construct a ring homomorphism such that $\phi(1,0)=(1,1)$ …

Comment: not found yet ...any suggestions.

Comment: As it does not exist. Where would $(1,1)$ be then sent?

Comment: @TomekKania how did you conclude it doesn't exists...

Comment: Uhm just a doubt on your formulation: when you say *into*, you are requiring the homomorphism to be injective?

Comment: Uh? No, i am just asking about the formulation of the problem in your first post: are you asking for injective homomorphisms?

Comment: @wisefool yes the question states the homomorphism to be injective...

Comment: Ok, then $(0,0)$ is not in the list… :) and again $(1,1)$ is not possible because $\phi(1,0)=(1,1)$ implies that $\phi(0,1)=(0,0)$, as $\phi((1,0)\cdot(0,1))=\phi(0,0)=(0,0)$, but  then $\phi(1,0)\cdot\phi(0,1)=(0,0)$, so $(1,1)\cdot\phi(0,1)=(0,0)$ which implies $\phi(0,1)=(0,0)$. Such a homomorphism is not injective.

Comment: @wisefool thanks ,understood ......

Comment: As a side note, there exists a homomorphism that sends $(1,0)$ to $(1,1)$, just not injective: $\phi(a,b)=(a,a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(1,0)\cdot (1,0) = (1,0)$ so $\phi((1,0))\cdot \phi((1,0)) = \phi((1,0))$. The only idempotents in $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ are $(1,0), (0,1), (0,0), (1,1)$. The first three are certainly possibilities. How about $(1,1)$?